# Recovering a pdf from quantile function

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods, approximation, inverse-function, quantile

Suppose I have $q(x)$ which represents the quantile function of a distribution. I can query the function for its value and derivative at any point (e.g. I can ask for $q(0.6)$ and $q'(0.221)$).

Is this enough to recover (approximate)  $p(x)$, the pdf of the distribution associated with $q$? How might one go about doing this?

Comment: The quantile function satisfies $q = F^{-1}(x)$ where $F(x)$ is the CDF. So you just have to compute the inverse of your quantile function to get $F$.

Comment: @user807138 Is this possible if I can only query $q$ for its values?

Comment: You want to solve the equation $g(p) = x - F^{-1}(p)$, since the zero of the equation satisfies $F^{-1}(p)=x$ or $p = F(x)$. To solve $g(p) = 0$, use the bisection method on $[0,1]$. You said $F$ was continuous, but be careful about situations where $F^{-1}$ is flat.  Those points mean that $F$ is not increasing at all (i.e., $F'(x) = 0$), so the pdf is zero at those points, and they have probability zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantile function is exactly the inverse function to the cumulative distribution function (assuming that this CDF is strictly increasing, at least), and the density function is the derivative of the CDF (assuming the CDF is differentiable). So $p(x) = \frac d{dx}(q^{-1}(x)) = 1/q'(q^{-1}(x))$.

Comment: How might I compute $q^{-1}(x)$ given that I can only query it (i.e. I don't have a closed form)?

Comment: Use the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to solve $q(t) = x$; then $q^{-1}(x) = t$.